# Can I filter a collection from xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a wpf-mvvm application.

I have an observable collection in my viewmodel

```
public ObservableCollection<BatchImportResultMessageDto> ImportMessageList { get; set; }
```

"BatchImportResultMessageDto" contains two properties..

result type..and message. Result type can be success or failure.

I need to display success in one list box ..and failure in another listbox.

I can do this..by having 2 observable collections in viewmodel to hold success/failure.

```
public ObservableCollection<BatchImportResultMessageDto> ImportFailureMessageList { get; set; } // To hold the failure messages.
public ObservableCollection<BatchImportResultMessageDto> ImportSuccessMessageList { get; set; } // To hold the sucess messages.
```

But is there any other better way so that i can filter it (without new two collections) ?

Comment: Yes - with markup extensions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461826/in-wpf-can-you-filter-a-collectionviewsource-without-code-behind

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) and make it a property of your view model, and bind to that instead of your `ImportMessageList` collection directly from the XAML.  Set your `ImportMessageList` collection as the Source of the `CollectionViewSource`, and then configure a predicate to do your filtering on the `CollectionViewSource`.

Something like:

```cs
private ICollectionView messageListView;
public ICollectionView MessageListView
{
    get { return this.messageListView; }
    private set
    {
      if (value == this.messageListView)
      {
        return;
      }

      this.messageListView = value;
      this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.MessageListView);
    }
}

...


this.MessageListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ImportMessageList);
this.MessageListView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(this.FilterMessageList);

...

public bool FilterMessageList(object item)
{
  // inspect item as message here, and return true 
  // for that object instance to include it, false otherwise
  return true;
}
```

Comment: how to filter  in CollectionViewSource  ?

Comment: So ..for lisbox's we can pass "MessageListView" ?

Comment: Yes, you can bind to your view property rather than your items collection.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by creating two [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) objects and setting a filter on each.

How to create a CVS in xaml from a VM binding ([Source](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html)):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="customerView">
           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country" />
           </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerView}}" />
</Window>
```

How to filter a CVS in a code behind (You can use reflection to look at the properties of your model if you don't want to make a reference to it. [Source](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007081301.aspx)):

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCVS"
                              Source="{StaticResource CulturesProvider}"
                              Filter="MyCVS_Filter" />
```

with (code behind)

```cs
void MyCVS_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo item = e.Item as CultureInfo;
    if (item.IetfLanguageTag.StartsWith("en-"))
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't always violate the mvvm pattern to put such code in the code-behind. If it's purely view related (filtering only) then it's fine to use code-behind. It may not be as nice as a binding or xaml property, but CollectionViewSource doesn't support that for filters.

Comment: @user2153378 it's okay because WPF and XAML also violate the MVVM pattern.

Comment: The code behind can also be moved into the viewmodel.