# In WPF can you filter a CollectionViewSource without code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, filter, collectionviewsource

Really the subject says it all.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyData"
    Source="{Binding}" Filter="{ SomethingMagicInXaml? }" />
```

It's not that I can't have code behind. It just nags at me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do pretty much anything in XAML if you "try hard enough", [up to writing whole programs in it](http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/).

You will never get around code behind (well, if you use libraries you don't have to write any but the application still relies on it of course), here's an example of what you can do in this specific case:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Filtered" Source="{Binding DpData}"
                      xmlns:me="clr-namespace:Test.MarkupExtensions">
    <CollectionViewSource.Filter>
        <me:Filter>
            <me:PropertyFilter PropertyName="Name" Value="Skeet" />
        </me:Filter>
    </CollectionViewSource.Filter>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test.MarkupExtensions
{
    [ContentProperty("Filters")]
    class FilterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        private readonly Collection<IFilter> _filters = new Collection<IFilter>();
        public ICollection<IFilter> Filters { get { return _filters; } }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new FilterEventHandler((s, e) =>
                {
                    foreach (var filter in Filters)
                    {
                        var res = filter.Filter(e.Item);
                        if (!res)
                        {
                            e.Accepted = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    e.Accepted = true;
                });
        }
    }

    public interface IFilter
    {
        bool Filter(object item);
    }
```

```cs
    // Sketchy Example Filter
    public class PropertyFilter : DependencyObject, IFilter
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyName", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyFilter), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public string PropertyName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PropertyNameProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(PropertyFilter), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public object Value
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RegexPatternProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RegexPattern", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyFilter), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public string RegexPattern
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(RegexPatternProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RegexPatternProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool Filter(object item)
        {
            var type = item.GetType();
            var itemValue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(item, null);
            if (RegexPattern == null)
            {
                return (object.Equals(itemValue, Value));
            }
            else
            {
                if (itemValue is string == false)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Cannot match non-string with regex.");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Regex.Match((string)itemValue, RegexPattern).Success;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Markup extensions are your friend if you want to do something in XAML.

*(You might want to spell out the name of the extension, i.e. `me:FilterExtension` as the on-the-fly checking in Visual Studio may complain without reason, it still compiles and runs of course but the warnings might be annoying.

Also do not expect the `CollectionViewSource.Filter` to show up in the IntelliSense, it does not expect you to set that handler via XML-element-notation)*

Comment: Did you actually test it? Last time I tried, it wasn't possible to use markup extension on an event... but perhaps it has changed in 4.0

Comment: That's neat, I wasn't aware of this new feature!

Comment: @H.B. I get an exception : Filters does not support values of Type PropertyFilter.

Comment: @Vishal: does it compile?

Comment: @H.B. No, It does not compile.

Comment: @Vishal: Did you properly set the `ContentProperty` attribute?

Comment: @H.B. I just copy-pasted your code and xaml. Also made the namespce changes according to my project.

Comment: @H.B. I also get an error saying : The type `me:Filter` was not found. Verify that.........

Comment: @H.B. The error about PropertyFilter is gone automatically. Now, I got a new error : Only Public or internal classes can be used within the Markup. FilterExtension type is not Public or internal.

Comment: @Vishal: Make it public then? (Though it should be internal by default, which won't help you if you try to use it from another assembly of course)

Comment: @H.B. I made the class public. In addition to that I changed the Filters proeprty to Collection<IFilter> instead of ICollection<IFilter>, added a setter to this property and removed readonly from _filters. Now it works fine. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @Vishal: Making the property settable should not be necessary if the type is one where the system can add items to the current instance. Well, if that helps in your case that's better than nothing.

Comment: @H.B. In my case If I set the value of Value Property of PropertyFilter to a static string it works fine. And when I change it to a binding to my ViewModel's Property of type string then it stops sorting. In short I am having a textBox and a DataGrid. When I type something in textbox I want to filter DataGrid.

Comment: @Vishal: There probably is no binding context, do you know how to debug bindings? If you think you have done everything to research the problem and you are still stuck, then ask a separate question. I will not explain the binding system in this comments section.

Comment: @H.B. Ok thanks. I every time look at the binding errors in output window. If there is a better way then can you tell me?

Comment: @Vishal: That's the most important part of it, you can only up the detail using [`TraceLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which usually is not necessary. Well, you also need to understand what the various errors mean and what common causes are.

Comment: @H.B. OK, I will check that. Thanks for your valuable time and help.

Comment: @H.B. I have posted a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157160/binding-a-property-inside-collectionviewsource-to-the-viewmodels-property . If you become free then please take a look at it.

Comment: I think I might have found the culprit for not compiling, might have to do with `public ICollection<IFilter> Filters` instead of `public Collection<IFilter> Filters`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71648935/2186184)

Answer (score 18):

Actually you don't even need access to the `CollectionViewSource` instance, you can filter the source collection directly in the ViewModel:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);
view.Filter = predicate;
```

(note that `ICollectionView.Filter` is not an event like `CollectionViewSource.Filter`, it's a property of type `Predicate<object>`)

Comment: While this may be correct and valuable information and all that, this strictly speaking does not answer the question that was asked i think.

Comment: @H.B., the title said "without code behind"; for me it usually means "in the ViewModel", but now I realize the OP specifically asked for a XAML solution...

Comment: @Jerry Nixon, this is *not* code-behind; this is the code of a ViewModel. Unless, of course, you consider any C# code as code-behind...

Comment: +1 because your answer is NOT code-behind, it is in the ViewModel.

Comment: If I may, the `ViewModel` providing view with a view sounds like a `Controller`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, it's not a view in the UI sense; a CollectionView is more like a view in the DB sense...

Comment: I will leave my previous comment for other people who might want to ask similar question. thanks @ThomasLevesque.

Answer (score 8):

**WPF** automatically creates a [`CollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview)—or one of its derived types such as `ListCollectionView`, or `BindingListCollectionView`—whenever you bind any `IEnumerable`-derived source data to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property. Which type of `CollectionView` you get depends on the capabilities detected at runtime on the data source you provide.

Sometimes even if you try to explicitly bind your own specific `CollectionView`-derived type to an `ItemsSource`, the WPF data binding engine may wrap it (using the internal type `CollectionViewProxy`).

The automatically-supplied `CollectionView` instance is created and maintained by the system on a ***per collection*** basis (note: *not* *per-* UI control or *per-* bound *target*). In other words, there will be exactly one globally-shared "Default" view for each *s̲o̲u̲r̲c̲e̲* collection that you bind to, and this unique `CollectionView` instance can be retrieved (or created on demand) at any time by passing the same "original" `IEnumerable` instance back to the static method `CollectionViewSource.​GetDefaultView()` again.

`CollectionView` is a shim that is able to keep track of the sorting and/or filtering state **without actually altering the source**. Therefore, if the same source data is referenced by several different `Binding` usages each with a different `CollectionView`, they won't interfere with each other. The "Default" view is intended to optimize the very common--and much simpler--situations where filtering and sorting are not required or expected.

In short, every `ItemsControl` with a data-bound `ItemsSource` property will always end up with sorting and filtering capabilities, courtesy of some prevailing `CollectionView`. You can easily perform filtering/sorting for any given `IEnumerable` by grabbing and manipulating the "Default" `CollectionView` from the `ItemsControl.Items` property, but note that all the data-bound targets in the UI that end up using that view--either because you explicitly bound to `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()`, or because your source wasn't a `CollectionView` at all--will all share those same sorting/filtering effects.

> What's not often mentioned on this subject is, in addition to binding the source collection ***to*** the `ItemsSource` property of an `ItemsControl` (as a binding *target*), you can also "simultaneously" ***access the effective collection of applied filter/sort results***--exposed as a `CollectionView`-derived instance of [`System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection)--by binding ***from*** the Control's `Items` property (as a binding *source*).

This enables numerous simplified XAML scenarios:

1. If having a single, globally-shared filter/sort capability for the given `IEnumerable` source is sufficient for your app, then just bind directly to `ItemsSource`. Still in **XAML** only, you can then filter/sort the items by ***treating the `Items` property on the same Control as an [`ItemCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection)*** binding *source*. It has many useful bindable properties for controlling the filter/sort. As noted, filtering/sorting will be shared amongst all UI elements which are bound to the same source `IEnumerable` in this way.   --or--
2. Create and apply one or more distinct (non-"Default") `CollectionView` instances yourself. This allows each data-bound target to have independent filter/sort settings. This can also be done in **XAML**, and/or you can create your own `(List)CollectionView`-derived classes. This type of approach is well-covered elsewhere, but what I wanted to point out here is that in many cases the XAML can be simplified by using the same technique of ***data-binding to the `ItemsControl.Items` property*** (as a binding *source*) in order to access the ***effective `CollectionView`***.

---

**Summary:**
With **XAML** alone, you can data-bind to a collection representing the *effective results* of any current `CollectionView` filtering/sorting on a WPF `ItemsControl` by treating its `Items` property as a read-only binding ***source***. This will be a `System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection` which exposes bindable/mutable properties for controlling the active filter and sort criteria.

---

**[edit]** - further thoughts:
Note that in the simple case of binding your `IEnumerable` directly to `ItemsSource`, the [`ItemCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcollection) you can bind to at `ItemsControl.Items` will be a wrapper on the original collection's `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()`. As discussed above, in the case of **XAML** usage it's a no-brainer to bind to this UI wrapper (via `ItemsControl.Items`), as opposed to binding to the underlying view it wraps (via `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`), since the former approach saves you the (in **XAML**, awkward) trouble of having to explicitly mention any `CollectionView` at all.

But further, because that `ItemCollection` *wraps* the default `CollectionView`, it seems to me that, even in ***code-behind*** (where the choice is less obvious) it's perhaps also more utilitarian to bind to the view promulgated by the UI, since such is best attuned to the *de-facto* runtime capabilities of both the data source *and* its UI control target.

Comment: I Very much appreciate the concept discussion in a clear fashion. Thanks.

Comment: -1 from me since instead of much discussion, @Glenn Slayden should've provided some actual implementation, at least relevant details - after all, that's what this website is all about...

Answer (score 1):

I had the following issues with the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462282/2186184) provided by [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) using .NET FrameWork 4.6.1 (old, I know, but unfortunately a limitation for my current situation):

| Severity | Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Error | XDG0012 | The member "Filter" is not recognized or is not accessible. |
| Error |  | Cannot set content property 'Filters' on element 'FilterExtension'. 'Filters' has incorrect access level or its assembly does not allow access. Line xx Position yy. |

This was easily resolved by changing

```cs
public ICollection<IFilter> Filters { get { return _filters; } }
```

to

```cs
public Collection<IFilter> Filters { get { return _filters; } }
```