# Binding a property inside CollectionViewSource to the ViewModel's Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am here with a new problem.

I have a DataGrid and a TextBox. I would like to filter the DataGrid based on the TextBox's value.

I have done that using `MarkupExtensions` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462282/2284240).

Now it works fine upto the Value property (Property of PropertyFilter class as mentioned in above link) is a string mentioned in XAML. When I change it to binding it stops working. Here is my XAML with binding:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}">
    <CollectionViewSource.Filter>
        <me:Filter>
            <me:PropertyFilter PropertyName="GroupName"
                               Value="{Binding SearchGroupName}" />
        </me:Filter>
    </CollectionViewSource.Filter>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

SearchGroupName is a simple Property of type string in my ViewModel.

I have also tried to change the binding as follows:

```
Value = "{Binding DataContext.SearchGroupName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                               Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

I have tried to debug it using System.Diagnostics as follows:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}">
    <CollectionViewSource.Filter>
        <me:Filter>
            <me:PropertyFilter PropertyName="GroupName"
                               Value="{Binding SearchGroupName, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
        </me:Filter>
    </CollectionViewSource.Filter>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

But then I get a compilation error : unknown property PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel for System.Windows.Data.Binding......

I think my binding with RelativeSource does not work because I think that CollectionViewSource is not a member of Visual/Logical Tree.

Thus I think my DataContext might be null. What are the solutions that you guys prefer if you are in the same situation?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try moving the filter into the resources of the framework element with the correct `DataContext`, using a binding like `Path=DataContext.<property-name>, Source={x:Reference <element-name>}`. Reference the filter where you need it using `StaticResource`.

This workaround is useful for [binding in collection containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model/6446923#6446923) for example.

---

Code should be something like this (untested):

```
<SomeElement Name="el">
    <SomeElement.Resources>
        <me:PropertyFilter x:Key="Filter1" PropertyName="GroupName"
                           Value="{Binding DataContext.SearchGroupName, Source={x:Reference el}}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupsViewSource" Source="{Binding Groups}">
            <CollectionViewSource.Filter>
                <me:Filter>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Filter1"/>
                </me:Filter>
            </CollectionViewSource.Filter>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: I have used `x:Reference` as you suggested. Now my Binding is correct as I put the ValueConverter and put a breakpoint in it, it shows expected value. But dataGrid is not filtered when I write anything in textbox. I have also changed the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropoertyChanged. But when I click on Column Header of DataGrid, the Filter works.

Comment: There is no way for the `CollectionViewSource` to know that the filter event method's results changed, you need to update it somehow. Don't know how one would do that though...

Comment: Thanks. Then I will have to find another approach for filtering data.

Comment: @Vishal: Did you find a way?

Comment: @stalbaig I have left WPF some years ago. So, I don't remember that. Sorry! my friend!