# How to make handler event in mvvm wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How to create Command for Event Setter handler when we follow MVVM pattern in wpf. My xmal code is as:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
             <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="horizontalListBox2_Drop" />
         </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't need a command to follow MVVM, you may just as well use that handler and code behind and invoke something on the VM. But you could create a [markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that does this for you without the need for that. Here is [an example where i create an extension to filter a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461826/in-wpf-can-you-filter-a-collectionviewsource-without-code-behind/6462282#6462282) that way. If you don't have complex parameters you of course can use the curly notation as well.

Comment: I am using MVVM Model in my application so i can not create Handle in the code behind. Please tell me this is how to possible in mvvm.

Comment: @naina: I told you how you can do it without code behind, also you are wrong: As i said, **code behind is not a problem in MVVM**, that's just a common misconception.

Comment: we need to perform some operation in this event and information is keep in view model so how to manage.

Comment: @naina: The markup extension will invoke a command of the view-model, so all the information provided by the view-model is readily accessible to the command anyway. You can also design your extension to forward the event args as command parameter if those are relevant as well.

Comment: I want like as by mvvm
   private void horizontalListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown3(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ListBoxItem)
            {
                ListBoxItem draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
                draggedItem.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }

Comment: @naina: I would just leave it at that if it works, creating an extension that does accomplish the same thing is unnecessary and complicated.