# CollectionViewSource filtering only in xaml

Tags: wpf, mvvm, collectionviewsource

My textbox provides the filtered string to the collection and when I enter new value in the textbox, I want my collection to be refreshed as per the new filter value. **I want to put the filtering logic not in my viewmodel or code behind but only in XAML.** The code is attached below. The sorting and grouping are working fine.  I have checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462282/5130106, it is almost doing the stuff but lacks when it comes to refreshing the collection, therefore, I am creating a new question, as I cannot find an answer.

Is there a way I could achieve this?

```
   <TreeView x:Name="SystemsTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SystemCollection}, Path=Groups}">

     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SystemCollection" Source="{Binding SystemsList}" Filter="{MyLogic}">   
        <!--Sorting of Systems--> 
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SystemName"/>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Version" Direction="Descending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
         <!--Grouping of Systems--> 
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="SystemName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>                
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: What type is the SystemsList? and why are you using `Source={StaticResource SystemCollection}`?

Comment: SystemsList is an observableCollection and I am using staticResource to use the collectionviewsource for sorting, grouping and hopefully filtering, if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to put the filtering logic not in my viewmodel or code behind but only in XAML

Not possible. You can't do this in pure XAML. XAML is a *markup* language. You should implement your logic in a programming language.

Givne your current setup, you should call `Refresh()` on the `CollectionViewSource` whenever the `TextBox` changes, for example in a `TextChanged` event handler in the code-behind.

If you want to refresh the filter from the view model, you should perform the actual filtering there as well. You may for example expose an `ICollectionView` that the view binds to. It makes no sense to define the filtering logic in the view but try to refresh it from the view model.