# How to choose columns from a query and display in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, entity-framework-6

I want to choose columns from a query with using the checkbox and Display in datagrid . In the following figure is an overview of the program :

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03BlG.jpg)

and with this code for search :

```
Database1Entities DBE = new Database1Entities();
var search = from c in DBE.Tbl_PersonalInformation
                     where
                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxFirstName.Text) || (textBoxFirstName.Text) == (c.First_Name)
                     &&
                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxLastName.Text) || (textBoxLastName.Text) == (c.Last_Name)
                     select new { c.First_Name, c.Last_Name };
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = search.ToList();
```

I would, for example if `checkBoxFirstName.IsChecked==true` and `checkBoxLastName.IsChecked==false` only `FirstName`  be displayed on the datagrid .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I filter a collection from xaml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923935/can-i-filter-a-collection-from-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

you could pass a filter method

```
public object FilterMethod(Person person)
{
var condition = false; // checkBoxFirstName.IsChecked==true
if (condition)
    return new {person.Name};
else
    return new { person.Name, person.SurName};
}
```

and use it in the select line
    select FilterMethod(c);

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your screenshot you are using WinForms and not WPF.
You can use:`this.yourGridView.Columns["First_Name"].Visible =  checkBoxFirstName.IsChecked==true;`

To set the the visibility of the First_Name column.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c24a0d7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you are using code-behind then in WPF you would do:
YourDataGrid.Columns[IndexOftheColumn].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

if you are using MVVM and want to hide the column in the view XAML:
<DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding firstnameVisibility}" ... >
where the type of the firstnameVisibility property is Systems.Windows.Visibility and set it to collapsed based on your checkbox value.