# UWP best way to use x:Bind and filter ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, observablecollection

I have an UWP application.

One view with a **pivot** control.

One associated ViewModel.

One model like this :

```
class Model
{
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

In the ViewModel, there is an ObservableCollection of model "model" like :

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> models = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
```

I want to display models in the pivot controls with each model **by category** in pivotitem. For example, PivotItem 1 will countain all models with category 1, PivotItem 2 will countain all models with category 2, etc...

a solution would be to create new ObservableCollection for each models filtered by category but this solution remains a little heavy in my opinion. To do for example :

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> modelCategory1 = models.Where(x => x.category == 1) [...]
```

That's why I was wondering if there was not a solution directly from XAML to filter.

EDIT:

In he view, in Pivot, i have 5 pivotitems each containing one ListView

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Models}" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Models}" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Models}" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Models}" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Models}" />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

EDIT 2 :

According to this [Can I filter a collection from xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923935/can-i-filter-a-collection-from-xaml) and this : [[UWP]CollectionViewSource Filter?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/15f3c875-e321-4eac-92ae-2f6226c33355/uwpcollectionviewsource-filter?forum=wpdevelop) i can't filter from a CollectionViewSource from UWP, so i guess i have to create new ObservableCollection that will contains Filter result like :

```
private ObservableCollection<Model> _modelsCategory1; 
public ObservableCollection<Model> ModelsCategory1
{ 
    get { return _modelsCategory1; } 
    set { _modelsCategory1= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
}
```

and :

```
var cat1 = from fobjs in Models 
         where fobjs.Category == 1 
         select fobjs;
ModelsCategory1  = new ObservableCollection<Model>(cat1);
```

Comment: If you are using data binding, you will need another property in your Model class for your pivot header to bind to.

Comment: I have edited to show the UI part

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your existing code to bind the **Category** property to the ListViewItem,

```
<PivotItem>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Models}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Model">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Category}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</PivotItem>
```

Comment: this will display all categories in my list, my problem is to display members in ViewModel.Models depending of the category in each PivotItem : the first PivotItem will display only models that match "ViewModel.Models where category == 1", the second PivotItem will display only models that match "ViewModel.Models where category == 2", etc...